# How to give a unique ID to each inserted item in array?

Tags: php

I run a situation where I put stuff into array like that:

```
    $current_pms[] = array(
        'from' => sofa_get_username($current_user->ID),
        'to' => $valid_user,
        'subject' => $subject,
        'message' => $message,
        'status' => 'unread',
        'time' => current_time('mysql', $gmt = 0)
    );
```

How can I mark each entry with its own unique ID so I can grab it later?

Thanks

Comment: Is a `key/value` pair not enough for you?

Comment: if the auto created one does not work for you you can: $current_pms[YOUR KEY HERRE] ...

Comment: I would like to be able to get specific entry based on its unique

Comment: you can with your current code.

Comment: Can you show me example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always self-assign incremental numbers, that's one option.

```
$id = count($array)+1;
$array[$id] = array (...)
```

Or you can just use any key/value pairs.

```
$array['id'] = ...
$array[123]  = ...
```